# Как отвечать человеку картинкой?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Как изменить код, чтобы бот отвечал картинкой?

```
bot.hears(/(мем|пикча|кинь мем)/, ({ reply }) => {
  reply('как сделать так чтобы ответил картинкой?')
})
```

делал бота в https://www.npmjs.com/package/botact

Comment: Скорее всего, изменить текст на линк  картинки, но это не точно!)

Comment: давно пробовал не помогает

Comment: .uploadPhoto(file) пробовали?